# Hashing running processes in Windows 7?

Tags: windows

What tool can I use to produce an MD5 hash of every running process in Windows 7?

I know it's possible since Process Explorer does this in order to calculate hashes to send to VirusTotal for analysis. Any clue about how to do it otherwise?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, no, it does not do that.  Enumerating the executable files that are loading in a process and calculating a hash on those files is trivial.  Start with CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()

Comment: You probably mean hashing **the main executable** in every running process. That's different from the process per se. Also, a virus may be sitting in a DLL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this powershell script:

```
foreach ($proc in get-process)
    {
    try
        {
        Get-FileHash $proc.path -Algorithm MD5 -ErrorAction stop
        }
    catch
        {
         $proc.name | out-file c:\error.log -Append
        }
    }
```